# Pictures not displayed in Excel

Tags: excel, image

Just want to ask if what's the cause behind and how to solve this issue. I have  pictures in excel that there're times that it is not displayed. It will just display a message `This image cannot currently be displayed`

Like this Photo:[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You've inserted the pictures as links instead of actually copying them into the file.

Comment: How did you add the image on spreadsheet?

Comment: Through Insert :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that excel can't find the image path.
Use following prefix before your file path for the server location.

```
window.location.origin
```